# Unable to add new rule for existing DMN model (Camunda 7.13.x to 7.15.x upgrade)

Tags: rules, camunda, dmn

I'm currently having issues with upgrading from Camunda DMN 7.13.0 to 7.15.0.
There is existing logic in my project which "merges" decision table content, which in fact adds new rules to an already existing DMN config.

When I upgrade the version I run into an issue that like this:

```
ValidationException: DOM document is not valid
Invalid content was found starting with element 'n0:rule'. One of '{"http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20151101/dmn.xsd":rule}' is expected.
```

Any idea how to solve this issue? Did anything change within the Camunda DMN library that i missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the full DMN file it is hard to help with a specific fix, but to answer your question: Yes, DMN support was upgraded from DMN 1.1. to 1.3.

You seem to be used the DMN API to merge decision table content as you wrote, so this may apply to you:

> As of version 7.13.0, the DMN Model API supported the DMN 1.3
> specification. However, any generated/exported DMN diagrams still used
> the DMN 1.1 specification. As of this version, the DMN Model API now
> generates DMN diagrams with the DMN 1.3 specification. Users that rely
> on the DMN 1.1 specification from diagrams generated by the DMN Model
> API should adjust their logic to use the DMN 1.3 specification.

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.15/update/minor/714-to-715/#dmn-model-api-generates-dmn-1-3-diagrams